# d3 order of label and checkbox chained

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, checkbox

My question is complimentary for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598074/d3-checkbox-label-input-order), but since I do not have enough reputation, I could not ask it in a comment!

I was trying to create checkboxes and labels dynamically using d3. Getting it to work with label + checkbox is easy. What I wanted to do was to put the checkbox before label by replicating this HTML code:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">Option 1</label>
```

The solution in the aforementioned post works, but I don't understand why the chained(nested selection/append) version is not working? (i.e. the code below)

```
var temp = item.append("label");

temp.append("input")
    .attr("type", "checkbox")
    .attr("checked", true)
    .attr("id", function (d,i) {
        return "checkbox" + i;
    })
    .on("click", function (d,i) {
        ....
    });
temp.text(function (d) {
        return d.text;
    });
```

I expect the code to add the label's text after input but it does not do so. Can someone please explain why? Am I missing something?

Comment: Honestly there are better tools than d3 for templating regular html. The problem is probably due to you making label's content of mixed type (tag and string). Wrapping the text into span should solve it

Comment: The thing is I am using d3 for some visualization reasons and I don't know if I want to use another framework. Why doesn't this one work?

Comment: Again, it's probably due to mixed type of the tag. `.text` concerns itself with string content, and it just does it's best guess on what to do when it also finds a tag inside. As I said, I'd wrap it into span